# Integrate Python flask script with Asp.Net web form application , C#,

Tags: c#, python, asp.net

I want to integrate the Flask script in my asp.net web application. To Achieve this there are two methods 
1) Calling the Python script using the new process with installed Python interpreter.
2) Calling the Python script using IronPython interpreter, hosted in your .NET application.

if I use simple python file it executes very well. But when I run flask python script it raises an exception "Flask Module not exist".

My question is that how can we add flask and other packages at run time 
or there is any best way to run python flask script.

I have tried both ways with simple python file
1) Calling the Python script using the new process with installed Python interpreter.
2) Calling the Python script using IronPython interpreter, hosted in your .NET application.

But it raises some modules exceptions

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Execute python Process...");
        Option1_ExecProcess();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Option1_ExecProcess()
    {
        // 1) Create Process Info
        var psi = new ProcessStartInfo();

 psi.FileName=@"C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
 32\python.exe";

        // 2) Provide script and arguments

     var script=@"C:\2B_Vision______________\ReadMVP\DARC_MVP.py";

        var start = "2019-1-1";
        var end = "2019-1-22";

        psi.Arguments = $"\"{script}\" \"{start}\" \"{end}\"";

        // 3) Process configuration
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;

        // 4) Execute process and get output
        var errors = "";
        var results = "";

        using (var process = Process.Start(psi))
        {
            errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            results = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }

        // 5) Display output
        Console.WriteLine("ERRORS:");
        Console.WriteLine(errors);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Results:");
        Console.WriteLine(results);

    }
```

I expect just execute the python flask script with no module issues.